# Вычисление, какому регулярному выражению соответствует строка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать калькулятор уравнений.
Уже появились некоторые идеи решений, но я не могу придумать, как написать скрипт, который бы определял, какое уравнение подаётся на вход.

Итак, у меня есть несколько регулярных выражений на разные уравнения.

Как мне проверить, какому именно выражению подходит строка?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55660/discussion-on-question-by-anatshir-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Получаем элементы
var $equation = $('#equation'),
    $res = $('#res');

// Создаём массив с нужными уравнениями
var equations = [
  {
    regexp: /^\d+$/,
    decision: function(equa) {
      /* Тут мы решаем это уравнение */
      
      //И выводим ответ
      return 'Обычное число!';
    }
  },
  {
    regexp: /^\d*x\=\d+$/,
    decision: function(equa) {
      /* Тут мы решаем это уравнение */
      
      // И выводим ответ
      return 'Умножение на X!';
    }
  },
  {
    regexp: /^\d*\/x\=\d+$/,
    decision: function(equa) {
      /* Тут мы решаем это уравнение */
      
      // И выводим ответ
      return 'Деление на X!';
    }
  }
];

// Создаём функцию для решения
var decide = function(equa) {
  // Создаём переменную для ответа
  var answer = null;
  
  // Создаём цикл для определения уравнения и решения
  for(var i = 0; i < equations.length; i++){
    // Проверяем уравнение регулярным выражением
    if( equations[i]['regexp'].exec( equa ) ){
      // Если уравнение совпало, то решаем его и останавливаем цикл
      answer = equations[i].decision( equa );
      break;
    };
  };
  
  // Проверяем, было ли решено уравнение
  if( answer !== null ){
    console.log( answer );
  }else{
    console.log('Уравнение не найдено!');
  };
};

// Запускаем функцию при нажатии
$res.click(function() {
  var equation = $equation.val();
  
  decide( equation );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="equation"><button id="res">Посчитать</button>
```

Comment: ага, а x/10=10 - это какой вид? а 10/x/10=10?

Comment: Твой код их не распознает

Comment: С каких пор отдельное число стало уравнением???

Comment: @Grundy, я должен все виды уравнений математики написать?

Comment: А разве не в этом вопрос заключается? :-) Плюс пока непонятно - что автор имел ввиду

Comment: И какие же у тебя _виды_ уравнений???

Comment: @Grundy, зачем мне писать виды?! Я написал, как их определять. Виды пусть сам уже записывает

Comment: @AnatShir, у тебя весь вопрос: _как сделать проверку на определение вида уравнения_ - чтобы проверять на что-то надо знать допустимые варианты. В комментарии ты указал как минимум: уравнение первой степени и квадратное уравнение. Это в свою очередь может быть - двумя разными видами уравнений, а могут относиться к одному виду.

Comment: @Grundy, из вопроса: _"Итак, у меня **есть** несколько регулярных выражений на разные уравнения"_ - уже есть, их не надо; _"Как мне проверить, какому именно выражению подходит строка?"_ - ответ на это дан.

Comment: @qwertiy, ты начальный вопрос посмотри

Comment: @Grundy, мой вопрос закрыли уже после последней правки